# relaciones entre clases en java

Tags: java

Necesito relacionar dos clases a traves de un atributo de tipo clase, pero al llamar al método set me salta un error de acceso.
Copio el código de las clases:

```
public class TuMascotaPrivate {
private String nombreMascota;
private String animal;

public TuMascotaPrivate(String nombreMascota, String animal) {
    this.nombreMascota = nombreMascota;
    this.animal = animal;
}

public String getNombreMascota() {
    return nombreMascota;
}

public void setNombreMascota(String nombreMascota) {
    this.nombreMascota = nombreMascota;
}

public String getAnimal() {
    return animal;
}

public void setAnimal(String animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
}
```

}

```
public class ClientePrivate {
private String nombre;
private TuMascotaPrivate mascota;
//constructor
public ClientePrivate(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public void setMascotaAnimal(String animal){
    this.mascota.setAnimal(animal);
}
public void getMascotaAnimal(){
    this.mascota.getAnimal();
}
```

}

**El error salta en la linea donde pretendo mostrar el valor de los atributos y me dice que el acceso a mascota es privado.**

public class Principal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ClientePrivate cliente1=new ClientePrivate("Miguel");
   System.out.println("El cliente: "+cliente1.getNombre()+" Mascota:"+cliente1.mascota.getNombreMascota()+" Especie: "+cliente1.mascota.getAnimal());
}
```

}

He buscado y probado soluciones y no he encontrado, por eso consulto y desde ya muchisimas gracias por su ayuda!!
Saludos

---

En la clase Cliente, en el método getAnimal va String no void y me faltó el return que ya agregué.
Ahora no sale ningún error al compilar pero en la consola sale lo siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ClientePrivate.getMascotaAnimal(ClientePrivate.java:20)
    at Principal.main(Principal.java:7)
C:\Users\carmigh\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score -1):

Tu problema es que no le estas dando ningún valor a tu mascota.
Básicamente creas el objeto cliente diciéndole que su nombre es Miguel pero al no asignar ninguna mascota esta se queda en null.
La solución sería crear un constructor en la clase Cliente que te pida el nombre y una mascota.

```
public ClientePrivate(String nombre, TuMascotaPrivate mascota) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.mascota = mascota
}
```

Posteriormente, en tu main hacer lo siguiente:

```
ClientePrivate cliente1 = new ClientePrivate("Miguel", new TuMascotaPrivate("Cletus", "Perro"));
```

Comment: Su problema es que está accediendo a un atributo con modificador `private` directamente en vez de usar el getter, no que este sea null. Eso sería un error diferente (Le daría un `NullPointerException`).

Comment: @Benito-B En la respuesta que ha puesto abajo comenta que ha cambiado una cosa en el `getter`, a parte la excepción es `NullPointerException` en el metodo `getMascotaAnimal` y eso es debido a lo que acabo de comentar.

Comment: Efectivamente. No lo vi porque lo puso en una respuesta y obviamente no era una respuesta :) StackOverflow no es un "foro", tiene un formato específico que se debe seguir siempre, precisamente para evitar estos casos...

Comment: Tienes toda la razón en lo que dices era por matizar solo. De todas formas, tampoco me quedan claro los estándares no he visto una página con todas las reglas para comentar, responder o preguntar.

Comment: Con un poco de sentido común se arregla. Una pregunta debe ser una pregunta, una respuesta debe dar respuesta a dicha pregunta, y si no puedes responder o quieres pedir alguna aclaración, usas un comentario. Hay múltiples páginas de ayuda que pueden servir para aclararse: [ask], [answer] y [help]. Cualquier otra cosa, está [meta]